# Eclipse JDT: Is there a refactoring to replace direct field accesses with setter/getter methods?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, eclipse-jdt, getter-setter

I know I can generate setters and getters for fields in the Eclipse source menu, but I'm very surprised it doesn't offer to replace the direct field accessors with calls to the newly created methods.

Does anyone know how to do this short of manual search and replace?

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a way.
Focus on the attribute, right click. Select "Refactor" -> "Encapsulate Field".

(Edited to explain why it works, even though the menu's title doesn't imply it)

The "Encapsulate Field" dialog-box will create getters/setters for you if they don't exist, *and* will change field-access to go through the getters/setters. The dialog automatically detects existing getters/setters so, for the requirements that you had mentioned, that would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks so much; it works beautifully!  I really need to read through the JDT refactoring documentation.

Comment: Here's another good answer to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21597844/2875073